# Get next XY position closest to a given target XY position

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

I have a dot (A) on the screen at a set XY position (e.g x= 100, y=200), and I have another dot (B) on the screen at a random XY position (e.g x=50, y=50).

I want to move dot B towards dot A in a straight.

How do I calculate the XY positions that B must move to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to calculate all integer positions between B and A, consider using [Bresenham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following should be able to give an idea. Point B is a random point with x and y values between +/-100.

```
var  A = {x:100,
          y:100},
     B = {x:Math.floor(Math.random()*201)-100,
          y:Math.floor(Math.random()*201)-100},
  diff = {x: A.x - B.x,
          y: A.y - B.y},
 steps = Math.min(diff.x, diff.y);
for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
   B.x = B.x + diff.x/steps;
   B.y = B.y + diff.y/steps;
   console.log("Step #"+i+" B moving to X: " + B.x + " Y: " + B.y);
// plotB(Math.round(B.x), Math.round(B.y));
}
```